# When does LOCK start during INSERT

Tags: sql-server

I have a INSERT statmenet that gets data by executing a stored procedure in `SQL Server 2012`.

```
INSERT INTO Employee
EXEC tp_GetEmployees
```

The stored procedure takes about 30 sec to provide the result.

1. Will the lock introduced for INSERT wait for 30 sec (for the SP to complete) ?
2. Or does the lock start only after the sp provided its result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INSERT` statement needs to acquire necessary stability locks before it starts executing (or, strictly speaking, as a first step of execution). The `INSERT` statement *contains* the `EXEC` call, so the `EXEC` is executed as part of executing the `INSERT`, which means that the `INSERT` has already acquired any necessary stability locks (for `INSERT` this necessarily has to be at least an Intent-Exclusive `IX` mode, see [intent mode locks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

Data locks are acquired as the data is being inserted, it would be impossible otherwise because one cannot simply guess what keys will be inserted, on what pages. As the data is provided by the `EXEC`, is not possible for `INSERT` to lock the data being inserted before actually having the data available.

For more detailed information, you can monitor lock acquisition and release in real time, eg. see [Using XEVENT in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlosteam/archive/2009/06/04/using-xevent-in-sql-server.aspx). Monitoring such will show you also whether the `EXEC` result is buffered or inserted as it comes (which is the natural next question to ask).

Answer (score 1):

In one query window, run this:

```
create procedure DoLittle
as
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'
    select 1 as a
go
create table T (a int not null)
go
insert into T(a)
exec DoLittle
go
```

In another query window, run this:

```
sp_lock
```

Which should produce output like this (for whichever SPID the first query window is running as):

```
spid   dbid   ObjId       IndId  Type Resource                         Mode     Status
------ ------ ----------- ------ ---- -------------------------------- -------- ------
54     1      1623676832  0      TAB                                   IX       GRANT
```

That is, an Intent eXclusive lock is already taken and held by the `INSERT ... EXEC`. But no other locks are held. No other query will be able to obtain an eXclusive lock against the table, but they may be able to acquire lower level locks.

Comment: `So no other query will be able to perform any data manipulation operations against this table`: that is an IX lock in your output, not X.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - you're right. I think I've been misthinking about Intent locks for a long time.